# Dropdown menu CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I created a dropdown menu for my Wordpress website. In this jsfiddle you can find the HTML and CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/N5H4c/

```
see jsfiddle
```

I have a CSS problem there. I created the dropdown menu but when I hover 'Menu item One' it stretches and gains more width. That should not be. The sub menu items can be larger but the menu item itself shouldn't change the size. Further there is this yellow background everywhere around it when I hover the menu and I would like to remove it.

Comment: "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."

Comment: The code is present in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update

```
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f7e600;
}
```

check jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/N5H4c/5/

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
position: absolute;
top: 38px; // your menu's height
left: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
```

to `#menu ul` : http://jsfiddle.net/N5H4c/2/